# Updating values on database using object oriented concept

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting values into database using object oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027619/inserting-values-into-database-using-object-oriented-programming)

I am very new to the concept of object oriented in PHP . I have been trying to insert the values of my form to the database using object oriented concept. I do not receive any error message but the values are not getting updated on the database .

Kindly take a look at the code and let me know what changes I should be doing in order to make it work.

Input.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="database.php" method="post">
Name : <input type ="text" name = "name"/>
Number  :<input type ="text" name = "number"/>
<input type ="submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

database.php

```
<?php
class Database
{
    var $host;
    var $user;
    var $pass;
    var $data;
    var $con;
    var $table;
    var $db;

    public function hostname()
    {
        $this->host="localhost";
    }
    public function username()
    {
        $this->user="cgiadmin";
    }
    public function password()
    {
        $this->pass="cgi";
    }
    public function databasename()
    {
        $this->data="j2";
    }
    public function connection()
    {
        $this->con="mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass)";
    }
    public function tablename()
    {
        $this->table="Insert into table(name,number) values('$_POST[name]','$_POST[number]')";
    }
    public function databaseconnection()
    {
        $this->db="mysql_select_db($this->data,$this->con)";
    }
    public function mysql_close()
    {
    }
}
$name=new Database;
$name->connection();
$name->databaseconnection();
$name->tablename();

echo "thanks for taking the survey";
$name->mysql_close();
?>
```

Kindly let me know the changes which needs to be done . 
Thank you .

EDIT

I made a few changes and still it doesnt seem to worl . Please help

```
<?php
class Database
{
    var $host;
    var $user;
    var $pass;
    var $data;
    var $con;
    var $table;
    var $db;

    public function controls()
    {
        $this->host="localhost";
        $this->user="cgiadmin";
        $this->pass="cgi";
        $this->data="j2";
    }

    public function connection()
    {
        $this->con="mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass)";
    }
    public function tablename()
    {
        $this->table="Insert into employee(name,number) values('$_POST[name]','$_POST[number]')";
    }
    public function databaseconnection()
    {
        $this->db="mysql_select_db($this->data,$this->con)";
    }

}
$name=new Database;
$name->connection();
$name->databaseconnection();
$name->tablename();

echo "thanks for taking the survey";

?>
```

Comment: You should avoid hard coding everything in the Class.

Comment: no code in mysql_close()

Comment: your table is table, I'm not sure if it's valid. Considering it's an SQL keyword.

Comment: @subirkumarsao as I said I am new to this programming language . So kindly help me with a sample code for the above example . Thank you

Comment: @Joset Give me a minute . Let me just change the name of the table and try it . Thanks for your quick response .

Comment: @Jathin: If you are just learning this language, then please don't waste any time learning the `mysql_` functions. They are insecure, and soon to be deprecated. Learn PDO. Here's an excellent tutorial : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: You don't specify var for variable. Just give the access specifier and variable name. like 'public $name;'

Comment: @Joset I need to start coding using object oriented concepts in php very very soon . So this is a learning curve for me

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$this->table="Insert into table(name,number) values('$_POST[name]','$_POST[number]')";
```

To something like

```
$this->table="Insert into sometable(name,number) values('$_POST[name]','$_POST[number]')";
```

Make sure you have your database updated as well.

It looks like **table** is not a valid name for a table. It's an SQL keyword.

And you didn't call any [mysql_db_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php) function or equivalent.

Edit:

mysql_db_query is deprecated. Use the alternative from the link given.

Comment: I did make the change but still it does not take the values . However I do not get any error message as well .

Comment: call mysql_db_query passing the string value returned from the tablename() function

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show me how it is done ?

Comment: check Mohit Bumb's answer. mysql_db_query is deprecated.

Comment: Hmmm Mohit bumb's answer does not seem to work . Could you take a look into the error