# Inserting values into database using object oriented programming

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to successfully rewrite old mysql-php code with deprecated mysql_* functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919277/how-to-successfully-rewrite-old-mysql-php-code-with-deprecated-mysql-functions)

I have not been able to insert the values into the databse . However I do not get any error message as well .

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="database.php" method="post">
Name : <input type ="text" name = "name"/>
Number  :<input type ="text" name = "number"/>
<input type ="submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

database.php

```
<?php
class Database
{
    var $host;
    var $user;
    var $pass;
    var $data;
    var $con;
    var $table;
    var $db;

    public function controls()
    {
        $this->host="localhost";
        $this->user="cgiadmin";
        $this->pass="cgi";
        $this->data="j2";
    }

    public function connection()
    {
        $this->con="mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass)";
    }
    public function tablename()
    {
        $this->table="Insert into employee(name,number) values('$_POST[name]','$_POST[number]')";
    }
    public function databaseconnection()
    {
        $this->db="mysql_select_db($this->data,$this->con)";
    }

}
$name=new Database;
$name->connection();
if(!($name->con))
{
    echo "'Error: ' . mysql_error()";
}

$name->databaseconnection();
$name->tablename();

echo "thanks for taking the survey";

?>
```

Comment: Why are you storing all of your function calls in strings?

Comment: Don't build SQL by [mashing strings together](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @k102 Where do I insert that query in my code ? Please help

Comment: @Blender I am new to this language . So finding it difficult to deal with it :(

Comment: @krish what changes should I do inorder to make it work

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need some magic :) Read about [quotes](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm) in php

```
<?php
class Database
{
    var $host;
    var $user;
    var $pass;
    var $data;
    var $con;
    var $table;
    var $db;

    public function controls()
    {
        $this->host="localhost";
        $this->user="cgiadmin";
        $this->pass="cgi";
        $this->data="j2";
    }

    public function connection()
    {
        $this->con = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
    }
    public function tablename()
    {
        $this->table=mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee(name,number) VALUES ('".$_POST[name]."','".$_POST[number]."')");
    }
    public function databaseconnection()
    {
        $this->db=mysql_select_db($this->data,$this->con);
    }

}
$name=new Database();
$name->controls();
$name->connection();
if(!($name->con))
{
    echo 'Error: ' . mysql_error();
}

$name->databaseconnection();
$name->tablename();

echo "thanks for taking the survey";

?>
```

Comment: Holy SQL injection vulnerability, Batman!

Comment: @Ruben Nagoga I am getting an error message . Is it a problem with my database ? Error message is :
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/jnagesh/public_html/SampleSurvey/MVC/database.php on line 20
Error: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/jnagesh/public_html/SampleSurvey/MVC/database.php on line 28

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/jnagesh/public_html/SampleSurvey/MVC/database.php on line 24

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/jnagesh/public_html/SampleSurvey/MVC/database.php on line 24
thanks for taking the survey

Comment: Is this a problem in program or an error in the database ?

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Could you please help me correct the error

Comment: Try once more, I have edited my answer. You didn't call `controls` method before establish connection to DB so your parameters for connection weren't defined.

Comment: Do not forget about [SQL injection](http://simon.net.nz/articles/protecting-mysql-sql-injection-attacks-using-php/). @Michael you are always welcome to edit the answer, anyway question wasn't about SQL injection. I think there are a lot of things which can be modified in my answer but I can't write whole code with all nuances, can I ?

Comment: Thank you Michael and Ruben. Wil go thro' the SQL Injection topic right away :) Thanks :)

Comment: @Jathin: Just as a pointer, the best way to prevent SQL injection is to use prepared statements. These don't exist in the old PHP mysql API, but there is the "MySQL Improved Extension" which not only has prepared statements, but the API itself is object oriented, so it seems like an ideal topic of study for you: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @RubenNagoga: Please read other questions/answers first and then improve your answer, for example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919277/how-to-successfully-rewrite-old-mysql-php-code-with-deprecated-mysql-functions

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

Modify tablename() function

```
public function tablename($nam,$num)
    {
        $this->table=mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee(name,number) VALUES ('$nam','$num')");
    }
```

Get values and call tablename() function

```
$name=new Database;
$name->connection();
if(!($name->con))
{
    echo "'Error: ' . mysql_error()";
}

$name->databaseconnection();

$nam=$_POST[name];
$num=$_POST[number];
$name->tablename($nam,$num);

echo "thanks for taking the survey";
```